# GCC Calling label as a function

Tags: gcc, label, call, gnu-assembler

All is in the title.
For some reasons I have to do it like this.

But when I compile my code, GCC (or GAS maybe...) displays the following error:

.../Temp/cc1C1fjs.s:19: Error: immediate operand illegal with absolute jump

Code:

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    /* Some code */

    ( (void(*)()) &&label)();

    /* Some code */

    return 0;

    label:
    asm ("push %ebp");
    asm ("mov %esp,%ebp");

    /* Some code */
    printf("Hello world");

    asm ("leave");
    asm("ret");
}
```

I'm sure that this should works because I tried to create a thread using CreateThread function (I'm under windows) specifing as entry point the address of label, and it works perfectly well.
So how can I ensure that the compiler accepting this syntax?
Or there is anothers ways for doing that?

Comment: Next time, indent your code with four spaces so it's treated like code. Select your code and press ^K.

Comment: as a point of learning, why are you using a label as a function pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you, but I do have a couple of suggestions:

1. Run `gcc -S file.c` and look at line #19 to see if you can spot what the actual problem is.
2. Look through the rest of the (short) `.s` file to see if anything is obviously amiss. For example, my version of `gcc` seems to decide that everything after `return 0` is dead code, so none of your `asm` code nor the `printf` actually make it to the assembler.
3. Can't this code be moved into a function? This way you'll get the prologue/epilogue for free; taking the address would also be less fraught with difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a part of the problem:

1. @aix you have right, GCC remove
   everything of the main function
   after `return 0;`, I fixed this
   replacing it by

   ```
   asm("leave");
   asm("xor %eax,%eax");
   asm("ret");
   ```

   Now the code after my label is generated.
2. Running `gcc -S file.c` then
       `gcc file.s -o file.exe`, of course it displays the error and at
   the error line there is `call *$L2`
   (L2 is label in my c file). It works
   by replacing it by `call L2`.

   Now the code after my label and after my call in main is
   executed and the program properly
   terminates with state 0.

But I don't want to have to do that each time I will compile.
Is it normal that GCC write `call *$L2` rather than `call L2`?